# Linear regression instance not fitting yet

Tags: python, machine-learning

```
enter code here

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

splitting the data to x and y

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('Position_Salaries.csv')
x = dataset.iloc[:,1:-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:,-1].values
```

training our model

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lin_reg = LinearRegression()
lin_reg.fit(x,y)
```

applying fitting methods on independent variable x

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
poly_reg = PolynomialFeatures(degree = 2)
x_poly = poly_reg.fit_transform(x)
lin_reg_2 = LinearRegression(x_poly,y)
```

this is the result of fitting , its already fitting and i get the output but in visualizing i get error.

```
fitting outpput
print(x_poly)
[[  1.   1.   1.]
[  1.   2.   4.]
[  1.   3.   9.]
[  1.   4.  16.]
[  1.   5.  25.]
[  1.   6.  36.]
[  1.   7.  49.]
[  1.   8.  64.]
[  1.   9.  81.]
[  1.  10. 100.]]
```

visualizing

```
plt.scatter(x,y,color = 'red')
plt.plot(x,lin_reg_2.predict(poly_reg.fit_transform(x)),color = 'blue')
plt.title('Truth or Bluff (linear regression)')
plt.xlabel('possition level')
plt.ylabel('salary')
plt.show()
```

error

```
1 plt.scatter(x,y,color = 'red')
----> 2 plt.plot(x,lin_reg_2.predict(poly_reg.fit_transform(x)),color = 
'blue')
3 plt.title('Truth or Bluff (linear regression)')
4 plt.xlabel('possition level')
5 plt.ylabel('salary')

966     if not attrs:
--> 967         raise NotFittedError(msg % {'name': 
type(estimator).__name__})
968 
969 

NotFittedError: This LinearRegression instance is not fitted yet. Call 
'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator.
```

Comment: Instead of `lin_reg_2 = LinearRegression(x_poly,y)`, you need to call `lin_reg_2.fit(x_poly,y)` to fit the model before calling `lin_reg_r.predict()`.

Comment: You did it the correct way for your `lin_reg` model.

Comment: thanks dude it was useful